# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Display resolution degraded after updating from kernel 3.11.0 to linux-3.18.2

Tags: upgrade, display-resolution

Today i tried upgrading my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from Kernel V3.11.0-15 to V3.18.2 and was successful with my mission. However, while attempting to boot from the linux-3.18.2 version, I am noticing a poor display resolution in my GUI. Also, my monitor tries to adjust the screen display size (every time while loading the login prompt after boot) but ends up truncating part of the screen.

Please suggest any settings changes that can help here.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue might be with the default configurations that I used during the new kernel build process.  I was able to resolve the issue with these steps:

1. After rebooting with new kernel image (V3.18.2), i went to **Settings > Display** and tested with various available resolutions. Changing the resolution to 1366x768 worked in my case.
2. After applying the new resolution, A pop-up prompts you to confirm that you want the new resolution to be set as the default. Select <kbd>Keep This Configuration</kbd>.